# Special characters executing javascript code in R

Tags: r

I try to execute a javascript line which runs in JS console which is this:

```
window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*="/url"]')
```

I try to use it with the following script:

```
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(a_url)
re <-  remDr$executeScript('return window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*="/url"]');')

Error: unexpected symbol in "re <-  remDr$executeScript('return window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk"
```

Is there any difference in character I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslashes to escape the effects of the nested quotes in the string:

```
x <- "return window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*=\"/url\"]');"
```

It may look non-standard in the console, but internally the string is saved without the backslashes. You can check with `?cat`:

```
cat(x)
return window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*="/url"]');
```

In case you are still unsure, here's a second test. You can see that `\"` is saved as one character:

```
> y <- "\""
> y
[1] "\""
> nchar(y)
[1] 1
> cat(y)
"
```

Comment: I tried with the executeScript using this `x <- remDr$executeScript("return window.document.querySelectorAll('.atbk[href*=\"/url\"]');")` and a new error exists
`Error in out[[wInd]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3`

Comment: If you would like to ask a second question about using `RSelenium` and it's functionality please ask after researching and troubleshooting the specific error you are receiving.